# Image not seen in Gridview on databind through visual studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview

And structure of database is car_model varchar, car_type varchar, dist_travel int, mileage int,car_condition varchar, car_owner varchar, car_color varchar, fdata varbinary(MAX), car_price varchar.

When I configure the datasource then the image cannot be seen and all the other fields are visible in the gridview on pageload. I have stored the image in varbinary(MAX) type in the table.

Comment: You left out an essential detail: tell us how you bind the data to the GridView. That means providing any relevant markup or code. Simply saying "image not seen" isn't very helpful.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

maybe this can help you any further?
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/5089e0/show-image-in-gridview-using-Asp-Net/

Comment: Rather than linking to a document that may or not be there in the future, you should explain what your answer is. Links to things on the Internet often get broken due to link rot, and then someone who has a similar question will have difficulty finding the answer.